# How to get connected scanner list in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to get the connected scanner list(names) and bind the scanner names to combo box, for scan purpose. I am new to UWP, please share any link or code.

I have just installed the NTwain library from NuGet Package.

Comment: see this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/scan-from-your-app#enumerate-available-scanners

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. i want to bind the scanner name to combobox at page load(by creating  getScannerName method ) how to do that ?

Comment: Is it possible to use TWAIN dll in UWP ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to bind the scanner name to combobox at page load(by creating getScannerName method ) how to do that ?

For your requirement, you could use `DeviceWatcher` to enumerate all `ImageScanner`. Then bind the result to the `ListView`. For more detail you could refer [**DeviceEnumerationAndPairing**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) official code sample scenario 2.

```
private void StartWatcher()
    {
        startWatcherButton.IsEnabled = false;
        ResultCollection.Clear();

        // First get the device selector chosen by the UI.
        DeviceSelectorInfo deviceSelectorInfo = (DeviceSelectorInfo)selectorComboBox.SelectedItem;

        if (null == deviceSelectorInfo.Selector)
        {
            // If the a pre-canned device class selector was chosen, call the DeviceClass overload
            deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(deviceSelectorInfo.DeviceClassSelector);
        }
        else if (deviceSelectorInfo.Kind == DeviceInformationKind.Unknown)
        {
            // Use AQS string selector from dynamic call to a device api's GetDeviceSelector call
            // Kind will be determined by the selector
            deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                deviceSelectorInfo.Selector, 
                null // don't request additional properties for this sample
                );
        }
        else
        {
            // Kind is specified in the selector info
            deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                deviceSelectorInfo.Selector,
                null, // don't request additional properties for this sample
                deviceSelectorInfo.Kind);
        }

        // Hook up handlers for the watcher events before starting the watcher

        handlerAdded = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformation>(async (watcher, deviceInfo) =>
        {
            // Since we have the collection databound to a UI element, we need to update the collection on the UI thread.
            await rootPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
            {
                ResultCollection.Add(new DeviceInformationDisplay(deviceInfo));

                rootPage.NotifyUser(
                    String.Format("{0} devices found.", ResultCollection.Count),
                    NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            });
        });
        deviceWatcher.Added += handlerAdded;

        handlerUpdated = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>(async (watcher, deviceInfoUpdate) =>
        {
            // Since we have the collection databound to a UI element, we need to update the collection on the UI thread.
            await rootPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
            {
                // Find the corresponding updated DeviceInformation in the collection and pass the update object
                // to the Update method of the existing DeviceInformation. This automatically updates the object
                // for us.
                foreach (DeviceInformationDisplay deviceInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
                {
                    if (deviceInfoDisp.Id == deviceInfoUpdate.Id)
                    {
                        deviceInfoDisp.Update(deviceInfoUpdate);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        deviceWatcher.Updated += handlerUpdated;

        handlerRemoved = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>(async (watcher, deviceInfoUpdate) =>
        {
            // Since we have the collection databound to a UI element, we need to update the collection on the UI thread.
            await rootPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
            {
                // Find the corresponding DeviceInformation in the collection and remove it
                foreach (DeviceInformationDisplay deviceInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
                {
                    if (deviceInfoDisp.Id == deviceInfoUpdate.Id)
                    {
                        ResultCollection.Remove(deviceInfoDisp);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                rootPage.NotifyUser(
                    String.Format("{0} devices found.", ResultCollection.Count), 
                    NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            });
        });
        deviceWatcher.Removed += handlerRemoved;

        handlerEnumCompleted = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, Object>(async (watcher, obj) =>
        {
            await rootPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser(
                    String.Format("{0} devices found. Enumeration completed. Watching for updates...", ResultCollection.Count),
                    NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            });
        });
        deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += handlerEnumCompleted;

        handlerStopped = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, Object>(async (watcher, obj) =>
        {
            await rootPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser(
                    String.Format("{0} devices found. Watcher {1}.", 
                        ResultCollection.Count,
                        DeviceWatcherStatus.Aborted == watcher.Status ? "aborted" : "stopped"),
                    NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            });
        });
        deviceWatcher.Stopped += handlerStopped;

        rootPage.NotifyUser("Starting Watcher...", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        deviceWatcher.Start();
        stopWatcherButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much your time and your answer. :) Now it works. do you have any idea how to scan image through auto feeder scanner in uwp. Please share a link or code. Thank you again :)

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/scan-from-your-app#scan).

Comment: This is windows 8 code [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scan-Runtime-API-Sample-5703b7a2) and you could refer it's code.

Comment: thank you :) have you tried this sample code for scan from Flatbed scanner ?

Comment: Sorry, we have no Flatbed scanner such device.

Comment: for auto feeder ?